# Wrap function parameters complexType in an element

Tags: wsdl, spyne

I am trying to implement an existing webservice with Spyne. 
I have a function that takes two parameters, for which the WSDL should look like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified" >
    <s:element name="getData">
      <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="login" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
[...]
```

My code contains the following decorator for this function:

```
@rpc(String(min_occurs=0, max_occurs=1, nillable=False),
     String(min_occurs=0, max_occurs=1, nillable=False),
     _returns=Unicode)
def getData(self, login, password):
     return 'data'
```

Which produces this WSDL:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/">
        <xs:complexType name="getData">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
[...]
```

So instead of an element containing a complexType I just have a bare complexType. This difference causes issues with clients that are compatible with the existing implementation. Is there a way to wrap the complexType in an element using Spyne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spyne's wsdl should contain both:

```
<xs:complexType name="getData"> (...) </xs:complexType>
```

and

```
<s:element name="getData" type="tns:getData">
```

Having complexType inside element is equivalent to having it outside with proper referral like this, so your parser should be able to cope with both forms.

If you don't have any control over the client, as that's often the case in such situations, you have no option but to patch Spyne. If you want to go that route, please join spyne ml (http://lists.spyne.io/listinfo/people) so we can talk.

Comment: Thanks @burak-arslan, that answers my question perfectly. Indeed, I do not have any control over the clients. These clients work with the original implementations, but not with mine. After reading your answer I do not think that the difference between the WSDL's is the cause of these problems. I have another idea about what might be causing these issues, but I will follow up on the mailing list instead of going off-topic here.

Comment: @qvdb did you ever get anywhere with this? i'm having the same problem, and while existing clients continue to work when they use the old wsdl, any time they try to update to take advantage of some new feature we've added, svcutil.exe spits out something that would require they rewrite much of their client. also, there are weird duplicate nested types when you look at it in wcftestclient.exe.

Comment: @colons I still do not know what was causing the problems with these clients. We tried to reproduce their setup (Microsoft Office 2003 + Web Services Toolkit + SOAP toolkit) but could not get it to work. We stopped looking when we found out that Microsoft stopped supporting the software they were using around ten years ago.